# Ocultar diretório com htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código em htaccess que faço o direcionamento:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/novo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /novo/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ novo/index.php [L]
```

Porém existem links que contém **novo/empresa.php** e gostaria de que ao clicar aparecesse apenas **empresa.php**  sem ter que alterar os links dos menus. Tem como fazer isso no htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar *redirecionamento 301* nesse caso.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
redirect 301 /novo/empresa.php http://www.seusite.com.br/empresa.php
```

Espero ter ajudado.

**Update**
Como não é uma `url` apenas, você deve fazer uma regra de `RewriteEngine`
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+novo/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^novo/)^(.*)$ /novo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url/18361995#18361995

Você pode ver que esse problema é comum na comunidade:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194198/how-can-i-hide-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url/18361995#18361995
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770442/hiding-folder-in-url-using-htaccess
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642122/htaccess-hiding-a-directory-in-the-url-while-preserving-other-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Usei como exemplo a página empresa.php, mas se for apenas o diretório, posso usar dessa forma? redirect 301 /novo/$1 http://www.seusite.com.br/$1

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo.